# Javascript : Matching character between two strings from end to start

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the given entries of numbers matches the given result number.
Example:

```
var result = "8842";

var entry1 = "43";
var entry2 = "042";
var entry3 = "0842";
var entry4 = "842";
var entry5 = "42";
var entry6 = "8842";
```

entry4, entry5 and entry6 should return true indicating that it is a win combination. In other words all characters from entry must match the characters from result variable from end to start or right to left regardless of the string length of entry. I know we can start to do it with for loop like this:

```
var winning = "8821".split("");
var entry1 = "23".split("");
var entry2 = "123".split("");
var entry3 = "55".split("");
var entry4 = "8888".split("");
var entry5 = "21".split("");
var counter1, counter2, counter3, counter4, counter5;
counter1 = 3;
counter2 = 3;
counter3 = 3;
counter4 = 3;
counter5 = 3;
for(var i = entry1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log("Entry 1: " + winning[counter1] + " === " + entry1[i] + " : " + (winning[counter1] === entry1[i]));
    counter1 -= 1
}

for(var i = entry2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log("Entry 2: " + winning[counter2] + " === " + entry2[i] + " : " + (winning[counter2] === entry2[i]));
    counter2 -= 1
}

for(var i = entry3.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log("Entry 3: " + winning[counter3] + " === " + entry3[i] + " : " + (winning[counter3] === entry3[i]));
    counter3 -= 1
}

for(var i = entry4.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log("Entry 4: " + winning[counter4] + " === " + entry4[i] + " : " + (winning[counter4] === entry4[i]));
    counter4 -= 1
}

for(var i = entry5.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log("Entry 5: " + winning[counter5] + " === " + entry5[i] + " : " + (winning[counter5] === entry5[i]));
    counter5 -= 1
}
```

But I want to know if there is more efficient or shorter version using existing method that JS can offer for this kind of case? Like just using regex. TIA.

Comment: Please explain the logic better here.  I have seen this question already today.

Comment: try to use substr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String.prototype.endsWith()` method to get your result. EndsWith method determines if a string ends with the characters of a specified string and returns true or false based on that.

```js
const result = '8842';

const entry1 = '43';
const entry2 = '042';
const entry3 = '0842';
const entry4 = '842';
const entry5 = '42';
const entry6 = '8842';

const a = [entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5, entry6];
a.forEach((x) => console.log(result.endsWith(x)));
```

Comment: I think that is what I really looking for. Thanks, will test it for a while then will mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to determine whether one string may be found within another string,

```js
var result = "8842";

var entry1 = "43";
var entry2 = "042";
var entry3 = "0842";
var entry4 = "842";
var entry5 = "42";
var entry6 = "8842";
const testArr = [entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5, entry6];

testArr.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(result.includes(item))
})
```

Comment: if the entry='88' this will return true which is not what he needs

Comment: No as @MansourAlnasser if result is 8420 the entry4 will still return true since inlcude() only cares about the complete string phrase occurrence regardless of position which is not the rule of this case

Answer (score -1):

**This will test the entry from the end to start**

the function will cut the result from the end and compare it will the entry

```js
var result = "8842";

var entry1 = "43";
var entry2 = "042";
var entry3 = "0842";
var entry4 = "842";
var entry5 = "42";
var entry6 = "8842";
var entry7 = "88";
const testArr = [entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5, entry6, entry7 ];

testArr.forEach((entry) => {
  console.log(result.substr(entry.length * -1) == entry)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

search() also finds given substring:

```
console.log(result.search(entry1))
console.log(result.search(entry2))
console.log(result.search(entry3))
console.log(result.search(entry4))
console.log(result.search(entry5))
```

it returns -1 if substring is not found.

Comment: Welcome @Pawel Blaszczyk, thanks for your collaboration, they need to find the match from the end, the search() function will find all match